# How to apply css for a class within h2?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML code as follows

```
<h2><a class="toc-backref" href="#id8">Debug</a></h2>
```

How can I apply css format to Debug which is inside `<a>` (which is inside `<h2>`) with a class of "toc-backref"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could put a `span` inside of the `h2`, but that's not necessary. If you want to style the `<a>` inside of the `<h2>`, just do something like:

```
h2 a {
  // style here
}
```

Or you can give the link a class:

```
h2 a.toc-backref {
  // style here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
h2 .toc-backref
{
    /* Any style here */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also try

```
<h2 class="toc-backref"><a  href="#id8">Debug</a></h2>
```

your style will be in css

```
.toc-backref
{

  //your style....

}
```